# Connecting nodes of one graph to a node of another graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

do you know how to connect all nodes of one graph to a node of another graph?

```
for node in messages:
    graph.add_edge(graph.nodes[22], node, label="channel_of")
```

*messages* is a graph and both *graphs* are of the same type.
*graph.nodes[22]*, which is a channel, returns the node, but not as the node itself but as a *dictionary*.
That is why the single message node cannot be connected to the *channel*.
How can I create an edge between the channel and all nodes of messages?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should create another graph that will contain `graph` and `messages` graphs

```
messages = nx.empty_graph(10)
graph = nx.empty_graph(2)

space = nx.union(messages, graph, rename=('m-', 'c-'))

for node in messages:
    space.add_edge(f'c-{0}', f'm-{node}', label="channel_of")

nx.draw_networkx(space, with_labels=True,
                 node_size=400, node_color='#7d99f5', font_weight='bold')
```

[image]